# Why isn't my Thread starting and why it's having compile error “Use of unassigned local variable 'thread'”?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

My thread isn't starting at all. So I added *thread.Start()* and now I having the error *Use of unassigned local variable 'thread'*. The Form shows, but then nothing happens.

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {

            {
                PagSeguroWork.Execute(vlTotal, tipoPagamento, nrParcelas);
                thread.Start(); // here's the error
            };


            });

            using (FrmPagamento frm = new FrmPagamento())
            {
                frm.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to start the thread *from within the thread*.  Move `thread.Start();` to after the definition of the `Thread` object:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    PagSeguroWork.Execute(vlTotal, tipoPagamento, nrParcelas);
});
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to access thread variable in lambda which initializes thread variable (so basically tin this case it would meanthat you are trying to start thread from itself). Try moving `thread.Start()`  out:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => PagSeguroWork.Execute(vlTotal, tipoPagamento, nrParcelas));
thread.Start();
```

Also nowadays in general it is recommended to use in C# [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1) API and not to create `Thread`'s manually.